# Image gets corrupted when copied using custom Python code

Tags: python, fopen

Here is the code

```
def main():
    f = open("image.jpg", "rb")
    filedata = f.read()
    f.close()
    print "Creating Test Image"
    f = open("ftp_test.jpg", "w+")
    f.write(filedata)
    f.close()
    print "Done!"

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Im not sure, why but here is the original image

[image]

and here is the resulting picture from the code

[image]

I'm not sure what to do so I decided to come to the experts since I'm only 14. I am also adding more to it like TCP communication. So I can send files over the internet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're reading the file in binary with `rb`, so write back in binary too, by using `wb`.

```
f = open("ftp_test.jpg", "wb+")
```

From the official [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files):

> On Windows, 'b' appended to the mode opens the file in binary mode, so
>   there are also modes like 'rb', 'wb', and 'r+b'. Python on Windows
>   makes a distinction between text and binary files; the end-of-line
>   characters in text files are automatically altered slightly when data
>   is read or written. This behind-the-scenes modification to file data
>   is fine for ASCII text files, but it’ll corrupt binary data like that
>   in JPEG or EXE files. **Be very careful to use binary mode when reading
>   and writing such files.** On Unix, it doesn’t hurt to append a 'b' to
>   the mode, so you can use it platform-independently for all binary
>   files.